# magento 2 foreign key adapt

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with my project. 
I am newer and use **Ui component** in  my sale history table the filed **parent_id** is the order id in sales_order.

When the ui component request data, I can not filter data using order id because there is not order id in my history table.

How can I do when I send order id as a parameters and it can adapt the history id at same time?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My solution is override the **Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider**

and add field

**protected $transformFields = [**
        **'order_id' => 'parent_id',**
    **];**

thiis is the from key to target key.
and adapt field

```
if (array_key_exists($paramName, $this->transformFields)) {
    $paramName = $this->transformFields[$paramName];
}
```